# fql.multiquery new sdk

Tags: facebook, fql.multiquery

I cannot figure out what is wrong with this fql.multiquery and cannot seem to find any examples of the new sdk with fql.multiquery.

Ultimately I want to get the page name and page id(s) of the visiting user pages which they both administrator and are fans of.

$queries = '{

"page_admin_ids" : 
  "SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = ' . $afid . ' LIMIT 5",

"page_fan_ids" : 
  "SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #page_admin_ids)",

"page_name_and_id" : 
  "SELECT name, page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #page_fan_ids)"

}';

$attachment = array("method"=>"fql.multiquery","query"=>$queries,'access_token'=>$access_token);

$ret_code = $facebook->api($attachment);

print_r($ret_code); die();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$multiQuery = array(
'likes' => 
    ' SELECT ... FROM like ...',
'users' => 
    ' SELECT uid, name ' .
    ' FROM user ' .
    ' WHERE uid IN (SELECT user_id FROM #likes) ',
);
$multiQueryResult = $facebook->api(array(
    'method'   => 'fql.multiquery',
    'queries'  => $multiQuery
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace "query" parameter in $attachment with "queries".